# valueof массива в typescript

Tags: typescript

Помогите описать значение свойства для "answer":

```typescript
interface IQuestion
{
    readonly title: string;
    readonly answers: readonly [ string, string, string, string ];
    readonly answer: IQuestion[ "answers" ][ number ];
    readonly description: string;
}

const questions: readonly IQuestion[] = [
    {
        title: "What is the most common job in the world?",
        answers: [ "Doctor", "Farmer", "Teacher", "Cook" ],
        answer: "Farmer",
        description: ""
    },
    {
        title: "Title",
        answers: [ "Test 1", "Test 2", "Test 3", "Test 4" ],
        answer: "Farmer", // ожидаю увидеть ошибку, что здесь возможны значения "Test 1" | "Test 2" | "Test 3" | "Test 4"
        description: ""
    },
] as const;
```

Comment: У меня такая версия https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIEUCuEDOZgD2IAPAIIg4Du0OyEAHpCACa1QRzNEA2AnsniigA5gG0AugD5kAbwBQyZO049+cCtSg4AXMnJUaAbgVKOXEH2TqDUXfs05RITAFsARtHHGAvnLkxMEAR8ImQXOABrCCxcEJJSOkYIFjYzVQEwIRAxKQAKel0MbDxCeMkASlkTdjBMKBBkeh8-BCI8RvpkAF5kURNwqJiSolz5RUVrB11RAHIiCBmAGmQZsEoCJZWwAAt2BeWZmAI6zcPgADcF8UWTCY1oXUPjqCWTbytaVoowcuX+yOixTio1uVnuWmmM0CGwOXBwp0yuFOAEdMHBMhtrqDJg8VnD4TdFO84J82j9CWEAUNgWNxjiIb0oSBTswIJh6AioARgPCseMwTZHhiea8iR9kF88L85OJxZKwMYgA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К сожалению, тайпскрипт так до сих пор делать не научился. В некоторых случаях могло бы помочь `satisfies`, но тут и оно не прикручивается.

Поэтому делаем по-старинке: сначала объявляем переменную с `as const`, а потом проверяем, что получившийся тип соответствует всем желаемым огранияениям.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIEUCuEDOZgD2IAPAILIQAekIAJjslBHLUQDYCeyA2nlKAHMANMj6CRYkMNFh+UgLrIAvI2asQnHpOnaJs8TLkD5APmQBvAFDJVLdl3xg2EAFyHBAbmu31muCBwAd2gcN1IvGyY7DS5-IOgw7hBMAFsAI2h5CJ97ZFpcBH4AB3wiN20vAF9LSwQiPGQAR2w8QgDlHisbR2c3ACIAdQALODBkYAYwIZQUgga6lNmQZAArAjTx5amUQIIoNloAfj6hbzjgqFCePoARAgQwPZPkPoAxOCgU6Ge+gBVmBDTKA-ADCBAIAGs+vJTjZzgkXu9Pt9YXkCsVSiB+n1LJURF1kD1XC9fsAnBATmcAhcrtw-rgxgBGH7-BoAJhZDOQAGZOQ0ACzQ1HwqD9JFfYGo-I4QrAEptbG4xRwBh1AJgLyWMAcIooLAMto4UhMDAtTHGqBwLgqbW6ggwJpmw0UagQOgMKK+Limg1EbjybyHCzVGz9Zq+9o4IYETAHZAZND61p++Q4rU6lAAOVS0GACAA0hAODhXntiL8XTR6DkYsh-Bx-SJyFQqwx6-6Oo3kAAlDogCAAN2gZhUpDpzikU2hlbd1d+47dAiniiDvbc2YlecLxdLUHLIm4ADpj6QRPWYT3kAAfZBjvoTpdDaEmGq2lAAUUQQyTmIAEiqADU4DYYBaFIaloA6AluAhItNmQDdcwLIsSzLN97UdCMcBMeQ3AACnQh1w2TAIAEoYKLRQW1nBhzBrPwIMuNxPVybhQBgSDT02DioGQAAhER2MgkFBJAHjkBuC8WNrEU3CE3je0qZBVxnd1b2vfiNJBDSbmU4NkDcAADH82mQAAScxYI4JSRgYUAB2A0C60YwyDOQYynSIczLKLJSJk2ByQNoQyqm4RD+GQnc0IzDDiMxbCshqUBIFgRAUAAfRBaYEAhEz6lU6s8oCY0IB9EiLStERP0BIr-xwICgvA+JePMaogA):

```
interface IQuestion<A extends readonly [string, string, string, string] = readonly [string, string, string, string]> {
  readonly title: string;
  readonly answers: A;
  readonly answer: A[number];
  readonly description: string;
}

const questions = [{
  title: "What is the most common job in the world?",
  answers: ["Doctor", "Farmer", "Teacher", "Cook"],
  answer: "Farmer",
  description: ""
}, {
  title: "Title",
  answers: ["Test 1", "Test 2", "Test 3", "Test 4"],
  answer: "Farmer",
  description: ""
}] as const;

type QuestionsAreIQuestionArray = typeof questions extends readonly IQuestion[]
  ? {}
  : "questions should be IQuestion[]"

type NumericKeysFor<T extends readonly any[], A extends any[] = [], R = never> = A["length"] extends T["length"] ? R : NumericKeysFor<T, [...A, any], R | A["length"]>

type EachQuestionHasValidAnswer = {
  [key in NumericKeysFor<typeof questions>]: (typeof questions)[key] extends { readonly answers: readonly [infer A, infer B, infer C, infer D], readonly answer: infer R } ? R extends A | B | C | D ? {} : `Question ${key} has invalid answer` : `Question ${key} is invalid`;
}[NumericKeysFor<typeof questions>];

interface _CheckQuestions extends QuestionsAreIQuestionArray, EachQuestionHasValidAnswer {}
```

Ошибка несоответствия типов проявит себя на строке с неиспользуемым интерфейсом  `_CheckQuestions` - хотя он больше и не используется, он либо скомпилируется, либо нет. В приведённом примере получится ошибка:

[image: скриншот ошибки]

Comment: Спасибо за долгожданный ответ, не думал, что все настолько плохо!)